# Content assist doesn't work for java objects in Eclipse Juno IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

i use Eclipse Juno, the content assist doesn't work for me specially for Java object:

Example: When i type "na" content assist work and propose "name" for me, but when i type "." to get some String methods, content assist doesn't work in this case.

```
public class A {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name.toString();
    }

}
```

i get this exception stack trace:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.eclipse.recommenders.utils.rcp.JdtUtils.createUnresolvedType(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/TypeBinding;)Lcom/google/common/base/Optional;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/recommenders/internal/completion/rcp/BaseRecommendersCompletionContext, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) for resolved class, org/eclipse/recommenders/utils/rcp/JdtUtils, have different Class objects for the type (Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/TypeBinding;)Lcom/google/common/base/Optional; used in the signature)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3946)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3623)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.eclipse.recommenders.utils.rcp.JdtUtils.createUnresolvedType(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/TypeBinding;)Lcom/google/common/base/Optional;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/recommenders/internal/completion/rcp/BaseRecommendersCompletionContext, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) for resolved class, org/eclipse/recommenders/utils/rcp/JdtUtils, have different Class objects for the type (Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/TypeBinding;)Lcom/google/common/base/Optional; used in the signature
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.completion.rcp.BaseRecommendersCompletionContext.getReceiverType(BaseRecommendersCompletionContext.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.completion.rcp.calls.engine.CallsCompletionProposalComputer.findReceiver(CallsCompletionProposalComputer.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.completion.rcp.calls.engine.CallsCompletionProposalComputer.computeCompletionProposals(CallsCompletionProposalComputer.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.computeCompletionProposals(CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalCategory.computeCompletionProposals(CompletionProposalCategory.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ContentAssistProcessor.collectProposals(ContentAssistProcessor.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ContentAssistProcessor.computeCompletionProposals(ContentAssistProcessor.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant.computeCompletionProposals(ContentAssistant.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.computeProposals(CompletionProposalPopup.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.access$16(CompletionProposalPopup.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup$2.run(CompletionProposalPopup.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.showProposals(CompletionProposalPopup.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant$2.run(ContentAssistant.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: You might have multiple versions of `org.eclipse.jdt` and/or `org.google.common.base` present in your `eclipse/plugins` directory or at least your classpath. Delete the `.jar` doubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean your project if does not work then restart your eclipse with clean option 
-clean
by setting in eclipse.ini file in eclipse config home folder.
If not works then check your jdk libs in build path

Comment: If starting eclipse with -clean on commandline does not work, please report a bug to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Recommenders

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple reasons

1. **Errors** in code because when there is error in code then the assist does not work as it can not solve the references
2. **Restart IDE:** IDE is out of memory and system resources are consumed. In this case restart IDE
3. **BUILD:** If the project is not built properly, if then clean and build the project